# Python-check what position it is in a list

Tags: python, list

```
list1 = ['physics', 'chemistry', "dog", "cat","dog"];
```

I want it to say if I typed in an input dog it will tell me dog is the forth one and sixth one.

Comment: I have swapped the dupe target to a more suited question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehensions:

```
list1 = ['physics', 'chemistry', "dog", "cat","dog"]

string = input()
res = [i for i, el in enumerate(list1) if el == string]

print(res)
```

Output:

```
[2, 4]
```

Comment: thanks you just saved my course work like 20 mins of experimenting

Comment: for reference how does this work so i can use any information i scrounge for future reference

Comment: @jcdenton check this https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions